# Is there a way to check browser's current history state entries and change them?

Tags: html, browser-history, html5-history

Suppose someone comes to one of my page. I want if the visitor clicks the browser back button, instead going to the previous page, it redirects them to a feedback page asking for exit reason. Right now I'm using the following way, is that correct or is there any better way for this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onpopstate = function (event) {
            if (typeof event.state !== 'undefined' && typeof event.state.page_name !== 'undefined' && event.state.page_name == 'third_page') {
                window.location = "html3.html";
            }
        };

        history.pushState({page_name: 'third_page'}, "page 3", "html3.html");
        history.pushState({page_name: 'second_page'}, "page 2", "html2.html");
    </script>
```

Comment: It is generally VERY frowned upon to change the user's browser expected behavior. If you do this I would at least display a message to the user telling them what you are doing and allowing them to go back normally.

Comment: Yes, I've a plan for that as well via Exit Popup which will allow the visitor to go back to the actual page they need to. But for this I need to tweak the history entries, that's why my question.

Comment: Can anyone help here please?

Comment: you are asking if this is "correct" - well - does it break anything or cause bugs? no one has offered a "better" or "more correct" way, I would assume that means the answer is no, but you cannot post an answer like "no" on SO, so this is potentially a question that will never have an answer posted...

Comment: Actually I don't have idea if there is a more better way to do this or what I'm doing is correct or not. But yes, my code doesn't cause any bug though. I was just looking for a proper way (if any). Thanks for your help though.